# "The second best project"

Tags: comparative-constructions

> I implemented the system with that unexceptional idea and I have got the second best graduation project.

Is *second* the right word to use here? Is my grammar correct?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the meaning is that there was one project that was rated more highly than yours, then yes -- the grammar is right, but the sentence is a little clumsy. A better way to put it is, "I implemented the system with that unexceptional idea, which got me the second-highest rated graduation project."

This shows a cause-and-effect more clearly, which is what you're trying to convey: because you implemented the system, you were therefore recognized for it.

Comment: Yes, but it does not convey the idea that *even with an unexceptional idea, I still was able to get second place*    Your rewrite implies that the reason I got second place was because I started with an unexceptional idea.

Comment: Hmm, touche. I guess it would depend on the lead-up to that sentence as to how to make it sound the best.